# \leftmapsto inside tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, mnsymbol

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}

$$\begin{tikzcd}
     S^2 - S \arrow[r, "f_+"] & \mathbb R^2 \\
     (x,y,z) \arrow[r, mapsto] & \left( \frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z} \right) \\
     \left( \frac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{1-u^2-v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\right) \arrow[r, leftmapsto] & (u,v)
\end{tikzcd}$$
and
$$\begin{tikzcd}
    S^2 - N \arrow[r, "f_-"] & \mathbb R^2 \\
    (x,y,z) \arrow[r, mapsto] & \left( \frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z} \right) \\
    \left( \frac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{-1+u^2+v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\right) \arrow[r, leftmapsto] & (u,v)
\end{tikzcd}$$

\end{document}
```

The result is the below figure, but I want to change the direction of the arrow as marked in red. Furthermore, the above code throws some error. What is the problem and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: `mapsfrom` ?, see `tikz-cd` documentation, page 3.

Comment: Do you really need tikz-cd for that?

Comment: @Bernard Otherwise, how can I align this in a pretty way? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! \mapsfrom exactly solves my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Let me convert my comment to answer. Arrows types are listed in `tikz-cd` documentation on pages 3 -- 4. There is no `leftmapsto`, but is defined `mapsfrom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=tiny]
S^2 - S \ar[r, "f_+"]   & \mathbb{R}^2 \\
(x,y,z) \ar[r, mapsto]  & \left(\frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z}\right) \\
\left(\frac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, 
      \frac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, 
      \frac{1-u^2-v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\right) \ar[r, mapsfrom] & (u,v)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
and
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1ex]
    S^2 - N \arrow[r, "f_-"] & \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    (x,y,z) \arrow[r, mapsto] & \left( \frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z} \right) \\
    \left( \frac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{-1+u^2+v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\right) \arrow[r, mapsfrom] & (u,v)
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

*Note*: In LaTeX  is use of $$`for marking`displaymath`deprecated. For it is defined`[`and`]`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
     S^{2} - S \arrow[r, "f_+"] & \mathbb{R}^{2} \\
     (x,y,z) \arrow[r, mapsto] & \left(\frac{x}{1+z},\frac{y}{1+z}\right) \\
     \left( \frac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{1-u^2-v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\right) \arrow[r, leftarrow] & (u,v)
\end{tikzcd}

and\par

\begin{tikzcd}
    S^2 - N \arrow[r, "f_-"] & \mathbb R^2 \\
    (x,y,z) \arrow[r, mapsto] & \left( \frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z} \right) \\
    \left( \frac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \frac{-1+u^2+v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\right) \arrow[r, leftarrow] & (u,v)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your diagram without `tikz-cd`: ans `align*`environment will do, and `stmaryrd`  to be able to define an `\xmapsfrom` arrow. Note I replaced the displaystyle fractions with the medium sized fractions from `nccmath`, so the diagram looks better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, stmaryrd}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\xmapsfrom}[2][]{%
 \ext@arrow3095\leftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}\mapsfromchar
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
      S^2 - S & \xrightarrow[\hskip3em]{f_ + } \mathbb R^2 \\
 (x,y,z) & \xmapsto[\hskip3em]{}\Bigl( \mfrac{x}{1+z}, \mfrac{y}{1+z}\Bigr) \\
\Bigl ( \mfrac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \mfrac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \mfrac{1-u^2-v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\Bigr) & \xmapsfrom[\hskip 3em]{}(u,v) \\
\shortintertext{and}
 S^2 - N & \xrightarrow[\hskip3em]{f_-} \mathbb R^2 \\
 (x,y,z) & \xmapsto[\hskip3em]{} \Bigl( \mfrac{x}{1-z}, \mfrac{y}{1-z} \Bigr) \\
 \Bigl( \mfrac{2u}{1+u^2+v^2}, \mfrac{2v}{1+u^2+v^2}, \mfrac{-1+u^2+v^2}{1+u^2+v^2}\Bigr) &\xmapsfrom[\hskip3em]{} (u,v)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]